# How to reset react-form-hook with dynamic checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react-form-hook with Material-UI library and I'm trying to generate random checkboxes for each object that I get from the server.

I tried to use "reset" function from react-form-hook and that didn't worked.

Codesandbox for example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-http-ijj8d?file=/src/App.js
(I faked the data from the server into variable over there **only for example**)
Thank you!

Comment: Anyone can help please?

Comment: https://react-hook-form.com/api/#reset

Comment: @ritaj Hi, If you look at my codesandbox that I added I tried to use reset but it's not working

Comment: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/2151 this can help